# how to create test tear down with arguments in robot

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a test case that generates a 6 digit code through the api call. I need to set that code in a csv file in the tear down method. I cant find anything with teardown having arguments. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use other scoped variables in the teardown, such as global variables. A proof of concept code like below:

```
*** Variables ***
${number}       0


*** Settings ***
Test Teardown           Log To Console      number in teardown: ${number}

*** Test Cases ***

Test Foo
    ${number} =         Evaluate            random.randint(0, sys.maxsize)
    Log To Console      number is ${number}
```

Will output like this:

```
==============================================================================
Robot
==============================================================================
Test Foo                                                              .number is 5146383281982903720
.number in teardown: 5146383281982903720
Test Foo                                                              | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Robot                                                                 | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
...
```

Comment: My teardown is written in another resource file. Its not in the same file.

Comment: You could try using the `Set Global Variable` keyword to set variables in the global scope.